# Failed to initialize firebase v9 authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase and trying to add auth. After viewing several yt videos I made a sample source code. But it doesn't update new user to the auth. My code is as following

sample.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth,createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-analytics.js";

const firebaseConfig = {

  //config data

};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth();

function fire(){
  var email=document.getElementById("email")
  var password=document.getElementById("password")

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });

}
```

And the sample html code is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
  <label for="password">password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
  <button id="signup" class="signup" onclick=fire()>Register</button>
</form>

<script src="assets/js/sample.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ive tried several approaches other than button function, like in js,

```
window.signup=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj={
        email:email,
        username:username,
        password:password
    }
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,obj.email,obj.username,obj.password)

    //code
```

and `form onsubmit=signup(event)`

Answer (score 0):

Your need to pass app variable to `getAuth` function like this `getAuth(app)`

Also you need to add .value to email and password variables like this:

```
var email=document.getElementById("email").value
var password=document.getElementById("password").value
```

Comment: I've tried getAuth(app) and value thing. But still no luck

Comment: Have you enabled user authentication in `firebase.google.com` via `Email/Password`. Can you send me what error are console logged after running your program?

Comment: i have enabled email option in firebase. console error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: createUserWithEmailAndPassword"

Comment: + Uncaught TypeError: fire is not a function after submitting

Comment: Put double quotes around `fire()` in `HTML` like this `<button id="signup" class="signup" onclick="fire()">Register</button>`